# Stuck process: is it a bad sign?

Tags: process, osx

Sometimes a few process are in a stuck state. For example:

```
PID    COMMAND          %CPU TIME     #TH  #WQ  #POR #MREGS RPRVT  RSHRD  RSIZE  VPRVT  VSIZE  PGRP  PPID  STATE
99357  plugin-container 0.1  12:07.07 10   1    224  2097   40M    84M    66M    82M    2757M  91688 99346 sleeping
99346  firefox          0.4  48:54.20 29   1    265  16250  467M   172M   799M   538M   4210M  91688 1     sleeping 
88029- Aquamacs       1.2  31:24.12 4    3    126  268    19M    49M    32M    36M    777M   88029 152   stuck
```

Is it part of the normal life cycle of process ? Why this process in particular ?

What does it mean exactly ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is not necessarily a bad sign, but let me answer your last question first:

**What does it mean exactly?**

In the `top` source code (from http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1082/) the *stuck* state is referred to as identifier `LIBTOP_STATE_STUCK` (from `libtop.c`):

```
libtop_state_str(uint32_t state)
{
        const char *strings[] = {
                "zombie",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_ZOMBIE     0
                "running",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_RUN        1
                "stuck",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_STUCK      2
                "sleeping",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_SLEEP      3
                "idle",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_IDLE       4
                "stopped",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_STOP       5
                "halted",
#define LIBTOP_STATE_HALT       6
                "unknown"
#define LIBTOP_STATE_UNKNOWN    7
        };
(...)
}
```

Later in the same file, `LIBTOP_STATE_STUCK` is mapped to kernel state `TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE`:

```
/* Translate a mach state to a state in the state breakdown array. */
static int
libtop_p_mach_state_order(int state, long sleeptime)
{
        switch (state) {
                case TH_STATE_RUNNING:
                        return LIBTOP_STATE_RUN;
                case TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE:
                        return LIBTOP_STATE_STUCK;
(...)
}
```

**So a process in *stuck* state means that the process/thread is in an uninterruptible wait state**, which is how `TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` is defined in the kernel struct `thread_basic_info` (see http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/thread_basic_info.html):

```
struct thread_basic_info
{
(...)
       integer_t        run_state;
(...)
};
```

where `run_state` is:

> run_state: The thread's run state. Possible values are:
>
> (...)
>
> - TH_STATE_UNINTERRUPTIBLE: The thread is in an un-interruptible wait state.
>
> (...)

This is usually caused by a process waiting on I/O, that is, the process has requested to read or write to/from disk or the network and waits for the system call to return (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28operating_system%29#Uninterruptible_sleep or http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7002725 for more information).

(When not using BSD options, as it is usually the case in Linux, `ps` shows uninterruptible sleep as *D* state.)

**Is it part of the normal life cycle of process?**

Yes, it is. What is not normal is that a process *stays* in this state for a long time. *That's* a bad sign.

**Why this process in particular?**

Difficult to say. It is usually caused by I/O bottlenecks with heavy disk activity or degraded connectivity when using network filesystems (the most usual scenario, in my experience).

(This is a related question in Ask Different: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58697/how-does-stuck-in-results-of-top-relate-to-not-responding-in-activity-m.)

Comment: How can I find out which processes exactly are stuck?

Comment: @mareoraft In OS X, the ones with a 'U' state code in the output of `ps axug` or `ps -eo user,pid,stat,args`. In Linux, the ones with a 'D' state code with the same `ps` commands. See the explanation of the state keyword (OS X) or the PROCESS STATE CODES section (Linux) in `man ps` for more information. Or, in OS X, you could run `top` and look for processes marked as `stuck` in the STATE column.